# Getter and setter not working, Constructor value stays empty - ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor, null, getter-setter

I have a session with an object 'User', and I'm trying pass the session object to BLSecurity.cs. This class uses the User object to check the login status and return a boolean.

The problem is that 'Gebruiker', not matter what, stays null.

**BLSecurity.cs**

```
public class BLSecurity {
    private wk_Gebruiker gebruiker;

    public wk_Gebruiker Gebruiker{
        get { return gebruiker; }
        set { gebruiker = value; }
    }

    public BLSecurity() {
    }

    public bool GebruikerIsIngelogd() {
        return Gebruiker != null;
    }

    public bool GebruikerIsAdmin() {
        return Gebruiker != null && Gebruiker.gebruikerniveauID == 1;
    }   
}
```

In the Master file from my asp project I do the following in the Load function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    BLSecurity BLSecurity = new BLSecurity();

    wk_Gebruiker gebruiker = (wk_Gebruiker)Session["gebruiker"];
    if (gebruiker != null) {
        LabelTest.Text = gebruiker.voornaam;
    } else {
        LabelTest.Text = "no name";
    }
    BLSecurity.Gebruiker = gebruiker;

    ...
}
```

When a user is logged in, he sees his surname with the labelTest and when he logs out, he sees the 'no name'. So that part works, but there must be something wrong with passing it to BLSecurity.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, I've used the debuggin from VS and I had placed a red mark by the 'GebruikerIsIngelogd()' function. And I noticed that Gebruiker was null when I hovered over it. Also if it was not null it should return true and that never happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found the problem.

The problem was that I created a new instance of BLSecurity when I needed the function `GebruikerIsIngelogd();`

So I had in my Load function the set part

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    BLSecurity BLSecurity = new BLSecurity();

    BLSecurity.Gebruiker = (wk_Gebruiker)Session["gebruiker"];

    SomeFunction();
}
```

And in the function `SomeFunction();` I needed those methods.

**SomeFunction();**

```
private void SomeFunction(){
    BLSecurity BLSecurity = new BLSecurity();      //here lies the problem

    if(BLSecurity.IsLoggedIn()){
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

So the problem is this new instance of BLSecurity in `DoSomething()`

The solution was to move the instance above the Page_Load()

```
public partial class WineKeeper : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {

    private BLSecurity BLSecurity = new BLSecurity();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        BLSecurity.Gebruiker = (wk_Gebruiker)Session["gebruiker"];
        SomeFunction();
    }
}
```

This way I won't be overridden which would result in null.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found your answer. I would like to point out that you shouldn't name your variable the exact same as your class name.

Instead of this:

```
BLSecurity BLSecurity = new BLSecurity();
```

You should do something more like this:

```
BLSecurity blSecurity = new BLSecurity();
```

It may have worked out for you in this case, but as a rule of thumb this is bad practice because you can get ambiguity errors.

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right. I've picked that up wrong from a lesson from my class. I thought it was with capital letters because of the abbreviation of 'Business Logic', but it's just the same syntax as usually. 

Thanks for pointing that out.